# What the solution for: I can't access an application made in rails in the local network

Tags: ruby-on-rails, server, opensuse

I use openSUSE and I'm programing in Rails, but even with a "rails s -b 0.0.0.0" I never can access the application in another device in the local network, I've tried different servers 'WebRick", 'Thin', I also tried config my router, and I followed a lot of other guides I found here. But nothing make it works. I've tried at my Home and Work, and different applications I made just for test this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two solutions to resolve your problem.

Option 1, you must install `webserver` such as `apache` or `nginx` and install `serverapp` such as `passenger` or `unicorn`. And you must setup `Virtual Host` to run on your app.
Refer document how to install `apache + passenger` at: [document](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-rails-app-with-passenger-and-apache-on-ubuntu-14-04)

Option 2, you can use service which called with name as `secure tunnel services online` such as `ngrok`, `burrow.io`,...
You can refer document how to use it at: [document](https://www.sitepoint.com/accessing-localhost-from-anywhere/)

Comment: apache + passenger didn't work too. With burrow it worked, but it is not free, although I'll keep trying to find a way, and for now I will use the burrow.io